# Automatic inheritance of permissions, when databases are added afterwards

Tags: sql-server

How do I give a user automatic access to all databases that's being created or imported to a database server?

I have a selection of one user and two activedirectory-groups which have to automatically given access to everything created, restored and mounted. We are not able to do this manally as is appear to be at this moment.

Thank's in advanced,

Comment: For new databases that are created, you could try adding the user to the `model` database. For databases that are restored or attached, I don't know of any simple way.

Comment: I suspect Extended Events will be the way to go here.